# How can i open this github project in android studio?

Tags: android, github

I am trying to do android gallery multiple image picker program. I found lots of sample but i didnt run its on Android Studio. This project in link i have a problem too.

How can i running this project in the link?

[Project is here](https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker)

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on VCS tab in the upper part of Android Studio -> Checkout from Version Control -> Github.

Then you have to use https://github.com/ as host, auth type as password and username and password of your account.

After in git repository url you have to insert https clone URL in right part of the webpage (in this case https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker.git).
Choose a parent directory and a name of your project.

Done.